# Viewing Microsoft Office 2007/2010 files in C# winforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, ms-office

I have read a lot of articles and SO quistions about this matter, yet, no appealing solution has come to my sight!

what i need basically is:

- Viewing MS office 2007/2010 documents in my winforms application

  Editing is not needed, however would be GREAT if could be provided

What i Tried:

- I tried to use a web browser control after setting the registary flags to open office docs in the same browser window rather than saving them on my machine

  I tried to use the Edraw Office viewer component, however, i can't buy licences to all the target users of my application and the trial version is annoying with the "buy the licence" msg boxes appearing whenever i open and close the application

  I also have seen this SO question [How do I display office and/or pdf content on a windows form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490829) and the answer is not bad, however, although i don't need the editing feature but i still would like to be able to copy text from the viewed document. i.e. this answer won't work well for me

A final note: Using a web browser component would be perfect as i'm using it already to view PDF/html/txt files and providing a functionality to make it work with MS office docs would make the application just what i hope for it to be!

I have already tried to use this article:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304662
but the web browser is still offering to save the file on my machine. :S

Any Suggestions?

Comment: @ArsenMkrt: is it possible to view all office documents by that COM?

Comment: Oops do you need to open all kind of office documents ?

Comment: basically i need Word, Excel & Powerpoint..

Answer (score 0):

I google a bit, and found [DSOFrameer](http://skyeyefive.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!6B6EB6E6694659F2!464.entry) which was purposed for that, but found the project removed here is why [Location of DSOFramer Download](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/csharpgeneral/thread/127bd801-525d-41c3-8516-cac7c68ec43b/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439168/ms-kb311765-and-dsoframer-are-missing-from-ms-site)

this may be helpful

Comment: yeah i know about DSOFrameer .. and from what i know .. the best advice about using the DSPFrameer as one of SO asnswers under another question suggests is "NOT TO USE IT" lol .. it's so troublesome!