# Reading .xps file causes OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, out-of-memory, xps

When I use c# to read a .xps file, I get an `OutOfMemoryException`.
I got some information from [Opening XPS document in .Net causes a memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218681/opening-xps-document-in-net-causes-a-memory-leak), but it seems not work in my code.

My Code below:

```
using (XpsDocument document = new XpsDocument(xpsPath, System.IO.FileAccess.Read))
{
    FixedDocumentSequence fds = document.GetFixedDocumentSequence();

    int pageCount = fds.DocumentPaginator.PageCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < pageCount; i++)
    {
        DocumentPage source = fds.DocumentPaginator.GetPage(i);
        Visual v = source.Visual;
        FixedPage fixedPage = (FixedPage)v;

        fixedPage.UpdateLayout();
    }           
    document.Close();
}
```

1. When I remove the line `fixedPage.UpdateLayout()`. Through Win8's "Task Manager", the current program's use of memory increased 10MB each time while I read one .xps file.
2. When I add this line, the use of memory still increased about 1MB each time.

Any one can help me?

Comment: Your code does not contain `fixedPage.Update()`, did you mean `fixedPage.UpdateLayout()` or is the line missing from your code?

Comment: So sorry about that, It's fixedPage.UpdateLayout() and I updated my question.

Comment: Does `DocumentPage` or `Visual` implement `IDisposable`? It might be that these allocate native resources (my suspicion is raised by `GetPage(int)` being a method, not a property), and you're leaking resources as you iterate.

Comment: I add     
`source.Dispose();`
to my code blow `fixedPage.UpdateLayout();`. Still not work.